# One to one correspondence

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\{B_i\}_{i\in I}$ and $\{C_i\}_{i\in I}$ be families of sets. If $B_i$ is in one-to-one correspondence with $C_i$ for each $i\in I$, $\prod B_i$ is in one-to-one correspondence with $\prod C_i$.

Comment: That's true. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_i\colon B_i\to C_i$ be a one-to-one correspondence.

Recall that if $I$ is an index, and $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of sets, then 
$$\prod_{i\in I}A_i = \left.\left\{\strut f\colon I\to \cup A_i\,\right| f(i)\in A_i\text{ for each }i\in I\right\}.$$

Intuitively, you want to define $\mathbf{g}\colon\prod B_i\to\prod C_i$ by saying: "given $f\in\prod B_i$, let $\mathbf{g}(f)$ be the function that takes $i$, maps it to $f(i)$, and then uses $f_i$ to send $f(i)$ to $C_i$. This will give me a function from $I$ to $\cup C_i$, and since $f(i)\in B_i$ and $f_i$ sends things in $B_i$ to $C_i$, the resulting function will be an element of $\prod C_i$."

Try to write that down and see if $\mathbf{g}$ is a bijection.

Comment: I had problem with constructing g, now i proved thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\Zobr}[3]{#1\colon#2\to#3}$If we have a map $\Zobr {f_i}{A_i}{B_i}$ for each  $i\in I$ then the
Cartesian product of these functions is the function $\Zobr{g=\prod\limits_{i\in
I}f_i}{\prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i}{\prod\limits_{i\in I}B_i}$, where
$g(f)$ for $f\in \prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i$ is given by
$$g(f)(i)=f_i(f(i)).$$

You should have look at the definition of [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of arbitrary system of sets at Wikipedia or in Arturo's answer. If you understand the definition of Cartesian product of a system of sets, you should be able to understand the definition of product of functions given above. (You should also try to compare this with the case when $I$ is finite, which is much easier.)

The proofs I wrote bellow are formal, they won't be very useful to you unless you acquire the intuition about these things - in my opinion it could be good if you try to understand the finite case first.

**Lemma.**
Let $\Zobr {f_i}{A_i}{B_i}$ be functions for each $i\in I$.

- (a) If $f_i$ is injective for each $i\in I$, then $\prod\limits_{i\in I} f_i$ is injective.
- (b) If $f_i$ is surjective for each $i\in I$, then $\prod\limits_{i\in I} f_i$ is surjective.
- (c) If $f_i$ is bijective for each $i\in I$, then $\prod\limits_{i\in I} f_i$ is bijective.

*Proof.*
Denote $g:=\prod\limits_{i\in I}f_i$.

(a) Suppose that all $f_i$'s are injective. Let $f,f'\in \prod\limits_{i\in I}A_i$ and let $g(f)=g(f')$.
This means that for each $i\in I$ we have $g(f)(i)=g(f')(i)$. By the definition of the function
$g$ we get for each  $i\in I$ the equality
$f_i(f(i))=f_i(f'(i))$ and the injectivity of $f_i$ implies
$f(i)=f'(i)$. Thus the functions $f$ and $f'$ are equal $g$ is indeed an injective map

(b) Let each $f_i$ be surjective and let $f\in\prod\limits_{i\in I}B_i$.
Then for every  $i\in I$ there exists $a_i\in A_i$ such that $f_i(a_i)=f(i)$.
In the other words, $\{a\in A_i;
f_i(a)=f(i)\}$ is a system of non-empty sets.
Using [Axiom of Choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_Choice) we have that there exists a function
$h$ defined on  $I$ such that $h(i) \in \{a\in A_i; f_i(a)=f(i)\}$, i.e. $h(i)\in A_i$  a $f_i(h(i))=f(i)$ for
each $i\in I$. The last equality means that $g(h)=f$.
We have shown the each $f\in\prod\limits_{i\in I}B_i$ has a pre-image
and thus $g$ is a surjective function.

(c) Follows easily from (a) and (b).

---

In case you haven't learned about Axiom of Choice yet, you can read that part as: *we define $h(i)$ as an arbitrary element $a$ which fulfills $f_i(a)=f(i)$ (we know that at least one such element exists)* and simply ignore the point that this axiom was used.

---

You only asked about the third part. You should be able to find a simpler proof of this, if you know that a function is bijective if and only if it has an inverse function. If you know that for each $f_i$  there is and inverse function $f_i^{-1}$, could you guess what is inverse to $g=\prod\limits_{i\in I}f_i$? Can you show that this function is indeed inverse to $g$?