# Multiplication of cardinal numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $a_i$ be a cardinal number for every $i \in\ I$.

Let $\{A_i\}$ and $\{A'_i\}$ be families of sets and let $A_i$, $A'_i$ and $a_i$ be equipotent for every $i \in I$.

Then show that $\prod_i\ A_i $ is equipotent with $\prod_i\ A'_i $.

This seems obviously true but I don't know how to actually show the bijection between them..

Comment: Hint: Since you are given that $A_i$ and $A_i\!'$ are equipotent for each $i$, you can assume that you have a collection of bijections $f_i$, where $f_i$ is a bijection between $A_i$ and $A_i\!'$. These are your raw materials.  Your job is to figure out how to build the bijection for the product out of these raw materials.

Comment: It really feels that you are afraid to try things on your own. You should know that without chewing *a lot* on problems and trying hard you will not learn how to do this on your own. I say that because you ask questions which often appear in a rather similar form on this site before, and you often accept the answer in *minutes*. This signals me that you haven't really tried to tackle the problem on your own before asking.

Comment: Note that this is basically a reformulation of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140467/one-to-one-correspondence/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $i\in I$ you have a bijection $\varphi_i:A_i\to A'_i$. Define $$\varphi:\prod_{i\in I}A_i\to\prod_{i\in I}A'_i:\langle a_i:i\in I\rangle\mapsto\Big\langle\varphi_i(a_i):i\in I\Big\rangle$$ and prove that it’s a bijection.

This is what I call a *follow-your-nose* proof: there really is only one reasonable thing to try. All you’re given is the equipotence of $A_i$ and $A'_i$ for $i\in I$. All that gives you is the existence of the bijections $\varphi_i$, so either the result is very hard (unlikely) or somehow it must be possible to use those bijections to get the one that you want. Since a typical element of $\prod_iA_i$ is just a function $\langle a_i:i\in I\rangle$ from $I$ to $\bigcup_iA_i$, about the only thing to try is to apply the bijections $\varphi_i$ to the components of $\langle a_i:i\in I\rangle$.